# Ошибка вызова метода

Tags: c++, qt

Неожиданная для меня проблема:

> ```
> error: passing 'const Randomize' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
>              x = randomize1(index, size); 
>                                         ^
> ```

```
int randomize1 (int x, int size)
{
    int z = qrand() % size;
    if (x==z) randomize1(x, size);
    return z;
}

QString GetRandomString() const
{
    const QString
    possibleCharacters("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    const int randomStringLength = 12; // assuming you want random strings of 12 characters

    int x = -1;
    int size, index;
    QString randomString;
    for(int i=0; i<randomStringLength; ++i)
    {
        size = possibleCharacters.size();
        index = qrand() % size;
        if (x==index)
        {
            x = randomize1(index, size); // ОШИБКА ЗДЕСЬ
        }

        QChar nextChar = possibleCharacters.at(x);
        randomString.append(nextChar);

        qsrand(QTime::currentTime().msec());
        Sleep::msleep(10);
    }
    return randomString;
}
```

Подскажите как её решить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Проблема**

У вас метод `GetRandomString()` объявлен константным. Следовательно, он может вызывать только константные методы.

**Решение:**

Метод `randomize1`  тоже сделать константным.

Answer (score 3):

Т.к. `randomize1` не использует члены класса (всё что нужно передается через аргументы), имеет смысл пометить функцию как `static`. В таком случае неявный `this` в нее не будет передаваться вовсе.